# Insert multiple rows from result of Average by date and id

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, bulkinsert

I have a table with 1 result per day like this :

```
id |  item_id  | date       | amount
-------------------------------------
1       1        2019-01-01     1  
2       1        2019-01-02     2
3       1        2019-01-03     3
4       1        2019-01-04     4
5       1        2019-01-05     5
6       2        2019-01-01     1
7       2        2019-01-01     2
8       2        2019-01-01     3
9       2        2019-01-01     4
10      2        2019-01-01     5
11      3        2019-01-01     1
12      3        2019-01-01     2
13      3        2019-01-01     3
14      3        2019-01-01     4
15      3        2019-01-01     5
```

First I was trying to average the column amount for each day.

```
SELECT 
    x.item_id AS id,avg(x.amount) AS result 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         il.item_id, il.amount,  
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY il.item_id  ORDER BY il.date DESC) rn 
     FROM 
         item_prices il) x 
WHERE 
    x.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 50 
GROUP BY 
    x.item_id
```

The result is going to be the following if calculated on 2019-01-05

```
item_id |  average
   1         3
   2         3
   3         3
```

or, if calculated 2019-01-04

```
item_id |  average
   1         2.5
   2         2.5
   3         2.5
```

My goal is to run the Average query , every day that would update the average automatically and insert it in 5th column "average" :

```
id |  item_id  | date       | amount | average
5       1        2019-01-05     5        3
10      2        2019-01-05     5        3
15      3        2019-01-05     5        3
```

Issue is that every example i can find with Insert the Select they only update one row and they are over another table there is also the most recent date issue...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to see  running average every day. Storing the value as a separate column is bound to cause problems especially when the rows are updated/deleted, the column also needs to be updated and hence will require complex triggers.

Simply create a `View` and run whenever you want to check the average directly from that `View`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_item_prices AS
SELECT t.*,avg(t.amount) OVER ( PARTITION BY item_id order by date) 
  AS average FROM item_prices t
  order by item_id,date
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a2c3d305ae611cfdf0938585350a16d5)

Comment: issue is that this query takes around 3 minutes to run, it would make for an horrendous user experience while running it once and day and saving the resultat makes it a bit less horrible and actually usable.. ;/

Comment: @cjder75 . . . This answers the question that you asked.